# multiple part identifier couldn't be bound

Tags: sql-server

i am trying to make a query that finds the item number and change the shelf number based on the id in another table but i getting a

> multiple part identifier couldn't be bound

on `SET` and `WHERE` how do i fix that or are there another way around this

```
use [ISTABLocalDB]
SELECT
    ps.[ShelfNumber], P.[ItemNumber]
FROM
[file].[Item]  P  
 inner join [file].[ItemPart] PS on P.[ID] = PS.[ID]
 UPDATE [file].[ItemPart]
 SET ps.[ShelfNumber]='Test'
 WHERE P.[ItemNumber] LIKE 'N84754'
```

Comment: I think you should re-read how an `update` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE PS
SET [ShelfNumber] = 'Test'
FROM [file].[ItemPart] PS
JOIN [file].[Item] P ON P.[id] = PS.[id]
WHERE P.[ItemNumber] = 'N84754'
```